# How to also change the location of index files when changing the default build location in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, build, indexing, xcode3.2

I'm using Xcode version 3.2.2.

If I follow these steps with Xcode:

- create a new Cocoa application called "Test"
- in Info change the "Build Products Path" to "_build"
- build project

I find that there is still a "build" directory being created called:

```
build/Test.build/Test.pbxindex/<various files>
```

These look like the files that Xcode creates when indexing the project. Is there anyway to change this location so these go into the new "_build" location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've just tested the steps you outlined above in XCode 3.2.3 and I could not reproduce that symptom. Renaming the build products path to "_build" properly moves all build-related files (and the .pbindex) to that location. I have also built with the different XCode-project compatibility options with the same results.

Thinking this might be a bug in XCode 3.2.2, I've read the [changelog](http://mac.softpedia.com/progChangelog/Apple-Xcode-Changelog-7935.html1.2.3.) but no such symptom is reported, and I personally have not seen that before.

An option that *might* help (but it should NOT be necessary) is to set the Build Intermediate Files path (in the Info panel of the Project) to the "Build products location", but I presume you have already tried that. In my XCode, the only case where the .pbxindex files do get built in another location is when I force them to by choosing the "Custom location" in the same panel.

Is it possible that it's a simple oversight on your part and that you haven't removed the directory after the cleanup? If not, then some more information would be helpful:

1. perform a clean build
2. open up the debugger (CMD+Shift+B)
3. from the toolbar, make sure you have toggled "All Results" under overview, "By Step", and "All Messages" from the last combobox
4. right-click somewhere in the debug output, and choose the option "Open These Results as a Transcript File"

HTH

Comment: I hadn't tried the option that _might_ help. So I changed the "Build Products Path" (the intermediate files path seems to derive from that setting) and the index files moved to where I was expecting them. As you noted, maybe this was a small bug that they fixed in the version after mine. All good. Thanks.